# Does JNLP (java web start) require server cooperation?

Tags: java-web-start

I am trying to load a JNLP but my server always return a 404.  The path is correct and I haven't modified anything from the demo so I am certain that is not the problem.  Is it the case that my hosting simply does not support JNLP and I should find a one that does?  Or is it me doing something wrong?

Here is the test

http://www.alexandertechniqueatlantic.ca/test/webstart.jnlp

I am using the supplied demo downloaded from

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/deployment/webstart/ex6/webstart_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo/dynamictree-webstart.jnlp

Comment: It is usually nice to have the server insert its own address in the JNLP file when requested - makes the deployment more robust.  Other than that you can use a plain Webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server was blocking JNLP extension from executing.

Answer (score 1):

The only 'co-operation' that JNLP requires from the server (as far as I can recall at this instant) are:

- The server must supply all resources requested, the JNLP & any extension JNLP files, Jars, icons etc.  The 404 indicates that part is not happening as per plan.  Either the JNLP is not where you think it is, or (less likely, given it is the wrong error code) the server has been configured to disallow access to that document or directory.
- The server should provide the correct content-type for the JNLP.  We can look into that after you have sorted the 404.

Comment: Actually, the server seriously seem to be blocking JNLP extension it seems.  I moved the file to a different server and it worked fine without the 404 error!  Time to contact support!